# Hessian tensor equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying some curvature conditions on a warped product manifold $M\times_fN$ where $f$ is a positive real-valued function defined on $M$. I got the following equation
$$\frac 1f H^f(\nabla_XY,Z)+\frac 1f H^f(Y,\nabla_XZ)=X\left(\frac 1f H^f(Y,Z)\right)$$
where $X,Y,Z$ are vector fields over $M$, $H^f$ is the Hessian tensor (defined on $M$) of $f$  and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection on $M$. .
My questions:

1. What does this equation imply?
2. Under what conditions could this equation have a non-trivial solution $f$? What are the (non-constant if any) solutions $f$ of this equation?

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $T:= \frac{1}{f} H^f$, then $T$ is a parallel.

If $M$ is a closed manifold, then $$g+sT,\ |s|<\epsilon \ \ast$$ is
positive definite so that it is a family of metrics on $M$ whose
connections are same.

If $M$ is not closed manifold, then in $\ast$ we can not find
$\epsilon$

If $M$ is an Einstein manifold with nonzero $C$, then $${\rm Ric}\
(g)=C(g+sT)$$ It is a contradiction. That is existence of $T$, which
is not a multiple of $g$, implies that $M$ is far away from
Einstein.

[Add] $g_s:= g+sT$ so that \begin{align*} g_s(\nabla^s_XY,Z) &=
\frac{1}{2} \{ X g_s( Y,Z) + Yg_s(Z,X) -Zg_s(X,Y) \\&+ g_s([X,Y],Z)
- g_s([Y,Z],X) -g_s(
 [X,Z],Y) \}\\&=\frac{1}{2} \{ X g(
Y,Z) + Yg(Z,X) -Zg(X,Y) \\&+ g([X,Y],Z) - g([Y,Z],X) -g(
 [X,Z],Y) \} + T(\nabla^s_XY,Z)\end{align*}

since $T$ is parallel. Hence $\nabla^s=\nabla$

(2) In flat $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\nabla T=0$ iff $f_kf_{ij}=ff_{ijk}$ where index means a partial derivatives. Here if $f$ is a
liner function, then $T=0$, but I do not know nontrivial $f$.

Comment: Thank you. First: Is there a reference or a name for this result on closed manifolds? Second: I am not sure that there is a non-constant function $f$ satisfying this equation, do you have any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: I have quickly read two old articles about spaces admitting a second order symmetric parallel tensor(Eisenhart 1923 and H. Levy 1926). The second one says if $M$ has constant curvature then $T$ is proportional to the metric and the first says that T is reducible for a riemannian manifold $M$.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I fix some. And I do not know reducibility well.

Comment: Dear Lee, I failed to find a reference for that result on closed manifolds( I mean a family of metrics on $M$ whose connections are same).

Comment: It is followed from computation. I have no reference.

Comment: Why closed only?

Comment: I add more explanation.